# Does GCP ops agent receiver support kafka version 3.2.x?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-ops-agent

I am trying to collect logs/metrics from kafka connector in GCP.

I read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent/third-party/kafka#prerequisites)

It seems that ops agent only support till `Apache Kafka Version 3.0.0` and I am using Kafka version 3.2.3.

May I know if there is any roadmap of version support of Kafka in ops agent?

Or any alternatives I can do for this? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, there is no hard requirement that the version of Kafka you use is within the range documented. You're free to try using a newer version than what's documented (the Ops Agent will not forbid you from doing this), and it "might" work; it's just not officially supported or tested.

That being said, I tried running version 3.2.3 through the Ops Agent integration tests and they all passed, so there's a decent chance that 3.2.3 would work fine for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I know how you do your integration test? From the doc or your custom test?

Comment: I ran through the steps at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/tree/master/integration_test, however they may or may not be runnable by anyone depending on what level of access they have within GCP.